# How to use subscribe in Angular *ngFor?

Tags: angular, ngfor, subscribe

UPDATED:

I have this code in my .ts file:

```
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {
  statuses;

  constructor(settings: SettingsService) {
    this.statuses = [
      {id: 1, color: '#ccffcc', name: 'Status 1'},
      {id: 2, color: '#ffaa00', name: 'Status 2'},
      {id: 3, color: '#ffff00', name: 'Status 3'},
      {id: 4, color: '#ccccff', name: 'Status 4'},
      {id: 5, color: '#ffcccc', name: 'Status 5'},
    ];
  }
}
```

I have this code in my .html file:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let status of statuses">
  <mat-form-field class="col-3">
    <mat-color-picker
      matPrefix
      matConnectedColorPicker
      [matConnectedColorPickerOrigin]="'color' + status.id"
      selectedColor="{{ status.color }}"></mat-color-picker>
    <input matInput matPrefix type="text"
      [attr.id]="'color'+ status.id"
      matColorPickerOrigin
      #color1="matColorPickerOrigin"
      value="{{ status.color }}">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

I want to show a color picker, an input field with color hexa code, a status name input filed and a delete button. I want use this logic:

If user click on the color picker and choose a color, it will change the color hexa code input filed's value.

The user can add multiple statuses with unique colors.

Now I can't figure out how to use the `#color1` part of my code something like this

```
#'color'+status.id
```

Is there any solution or a best practice to change my code to work inside of an `*ngFor` directive?

Comment: You cannot dynamically generate template variables in Angular and you really shouldn't: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4581#issuecomment-148786554
Can you explain what you are trying to do? Posting your typescript code would also help

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Why do you want to define `#color1`? And how is the question related to `subscribe`?

Comment: What is matConnectedColorPicker?

Comment: I use the mat-color-picker module from github: https://github.com/tiaguinho/mat-color-picker this is define the matConnectedColorPicker

Comment: This might help: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variable-warning-notes